# "correct" / idiomatic way of including c++ libraries in project

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

I was wondering what the 'correct' way of including libraries is in a project.
Im trying to integrate llvm core with my project and I noticed the source has numerous cmake files.
If I want to integrate this with my project (a compiler frontend based on kaleidoscope tutorial),
should I convert my project to cmake?
If so, how do I include the library in my build?
Are there any 'valid' alternatives?

Comment: This would depend on your project's format, wouldn't it? There's no reason, for example, that VS would encourage the same process as Code::Blocks.

Comment: If you install LLVM system-wide, or somewhere in your [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html), isn't `find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)` enough?

Comment: As for the more general case, there's really no single "correct" or idiomatic way, because it depends on your project and the libraries it needs.

Comment: @JaMiT wdym format? What if not using an IDE

Comment: @Dmitriy_I *"What if not using an IDE"* -- Then whatever you are using to process your project. I named two IDEs for examples because their names sprang to mind. SCons and CMake are two non-IDE based tools I can think of. The point is not "IDE" but "build tool". Different build tools use different approaches/formats for defining their projects.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude which questions should I "be asking" about my library inorder to figure out the best method for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the correct way is not to do it.
The reason for this is because it makes it easier for people with dependencies installed to install and integrate your package in their system.

You ought to use a tool like `pkg-config` or such to find your dependencies from the running system.

The Meson build system has excellent support for this, `pkg.m4` provides macros for `autoconf` that you can use, and CMake provides `FindPkgConfig`.

Some packages do not use `pkg-config`, but instead provide similar `-config` style scripts. IIRC, LLVM is one of these. They usually also provide macros you can use with your build system but, if not, they're fairly easy to invoke correctly.

Meson also has support for the LLVM dependency: https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#llvm

IIRC, the LLVM project also provides a FindLLVM.cmake file you can use if you end up opting for CMake (but, IMO, CMake is a big downgrade from most build systems).